# Disabling only a couple error labels with the jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin and want to disable the error label containers for only a couple inputs. These inputs are the first two parts of a 3 part phone input (3-3-4).

I can set the messages to a blank string, but the display: block; of  still throws them all on a separate line.

I couldn't figure out how to disable just a couple inputs without specifying every input in the errorPlacement { }.

Something like:

```
errorPlacement {
  if phone_1, phone_2 --> show no label

  else --> show label
}
```

I do want to keep the error classes on the actual inputs though - and hell in an optimal world there would only be one label for the 3-part input group that spawned after the third input.

Any sugestions?

Comment: there are many validation plugins, which one are you using? maybe the one you're using could allow you to create a custom validation or even alter the way its phone validation works which sometimes is better than disable one thing and messing other

Comment: I'm using the http://jqueryvalidation.org/ plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it, if anybody else runs into something like this here is the solution:

```
  groups: {
      Phone: "hp_1 hp_2 hp_3"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr("name") == "hp_1" || element.attr("name") == "hp_2" || element.attr("name") == "hp_3")
        error.insertAfter("#hp_3");
      else
        error.insertAfter(element);
  },
```